# pandas-datareade and AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute 'fileno'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web import datetime   
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 26)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
```

and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    f.Close
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 611, in displayhook
    text = repr(value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 72, in __repr__
    return str(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 51, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 982, in __unicode__
    width, height = get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\terminal.py", line 33, in get_terminal_size
    return shutil.get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 1071, in get_terminal_size
    size = os.get_terminal_size(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I use Python 3.4 [wrong: <s>3.5</s>] with pandas 0.2 when the error occured. The same code on Python 3.6 with pandas 0.2 runs without problems on another work station. Anybody any idea how I can fix the error.

I allready tried to uninstall and to reinstall pandas and pandas-datareader but it didn't helped.

Comment: your traceback says you have Python v3.4... I just tried to reproduce it using Pandas: 0.20.3, pandas_datareader: 0.5.0, python: 3.5.4.final.0 - everything works just fine

Comment: I have corrected it. Thanks! Pandas was working on my machine and now produces these errors. I will try an Python update.

Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: saying `pandas 0.2` - do you mean `pandas 0.20`?

Comment: what does `sys.__stdout__` return in your Python 3.4 environment?

Comment: I have reinstalled everything as you suggested and now it works. Thank you very much!!!

PS: Yes, I meant pandas 0.20 - Sorry for that.